# Designing cluster to handle 1 trillion records database

Tags: mysql, database, cluster

Major use of that cluster would be to have add/delete/edit operations on individual records based on primary key.

Database itself is not complicated but main concern is handling the operations on that amount of data efficiently.

And database would be mysql and what amount of RAM would you suggest?

Comment: This question is way too vague. Trillion can be either 10^12 or 10^18 for starters.

Comment: its 10^12 why it should be 10^18? :o

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales

Comment: ah sorry for that confusion.. I meant 10^12.

Comment: One hundred billion dollars! </drevil>

Answer (score 2):

> And database would be mysql

Mysql is seriously inadequate for the task.

Get Db2. On mainfarmes. Call IBM. I mean LARGE mainframe.

NOTHING scales like DB2.

ANY idea what you talk her?

> what amount of RAM would you suggest?

What amount of DISC space? What amount of IOPS you need?

Hm, maybe call oracle. Their EXADATA stuff should scale up like that - cost is some millions for that.

RAM is not your problem, the rest is, or you cluster into thousands of nodes.